# Additional Page Keeps Being Printed To PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

So when I run the code the PDF gains an extra blank page.

Attempted to make the page break continuous.
Attempted to delete a character.

These delete the header and footer but they are required.

```
Sub Word_ExportPDF()

Dim i As Long
Dim CurrentFolder As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim myPath As String

myPath = ActiveDocument.FullName
CurrentFolder = ActiveDocument.Path & "\"
FileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, _
InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)

With ActiveDocument
For i = 102 To .Sections.Count

    .Sections(i).Range.Select

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    CurrentFolder & "Section " & i & ".pdf", _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, 
    OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportSelection, Item:= _
    wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, 
    DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Just creates an extra blank page to the end of my PDF.

Answer (score 0):

When a document has multiple sections, and the section break is of the type "Next Page" and is included this will, logically, generate an additional page. Header/Footer information for a section is stored in the section break, so if the section break is left out (or deleted), the Header/Footer information goes with it. So the described behavior is "expected".

There is no way to save a section of a document *directly* to PDF without one of these problems.

The way around it is to copy-transfer the section content to a new, empty document, remove the page break, and save that to PDF. The document can then be discarded without saving. For example:

```
Sub SectionToNewDoc()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CurrentFolder As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim docSource As Word.Document
    Dim docTemp As Word.Document
    Dim rngSource As Word.Range
    Dim rngTarget As Word.Range

    Set docSource = ActiveDocument

 With docSource
    myPath = .FullName
    CurrentFolder = .Path & "\"FileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, _
      InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)

    For i = 102 To .Sections.Count
      Set rngSource = .Sections(i).Range

      Set docTemp = Documents.Add
      Set rngTarget = docTemp.content
      rngTarget.FormattedText = rngSource.FormattedText
      rngTarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      rngTarget.MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
      rngTarget.Delete
      docTemp.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        CurrentFolder & "Section " & i & ".pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportSelection, Item:= _
        wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
      docTemp.Close False
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'll try this tomorrow and report back!

Comment: @Datolite Strange, because there's nothing in the code that closes the document that was active when the code starts. And I did test before posting. Did you make any changes to the code I posted?